# RegEx help - Find " but not ") (in a yacc compiled C exe)

Tags: regex, yacc

Here's an example string

(VIACODE VC2 "yyy ¬`!"£$%^-=_+;:'@#,./")

I've come up with this "(?!))

which appears to correctly identify all but the last quote

but my yacc compiler spits it out...

bad character: !
bad character: 
bad character: )

Is there another way of forming this regex that an old compiler might like?

Comment: yacc does not support regular expressions.  Maybe something with your lexer?  Not at all clear what you are asking.  What does "an old compiler" have to do with anything?

Comment: Truly I don't understand the structure of this 30 year old code I've been handed!